# Transforming a string of coordinate pairs into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I receive coordinates from a database as a string, but I need to transform it into a an array of objects in order to later use with Google maps.

I have managed to split and chunk the array in pairs, but I'm having problems transforming the chunks into key-value pairs.

```js
let coordinatesString = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, -80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030"

// split the string by , in order to get an array
let splitArray = coordinatesString.split(', ')

function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0,len=arr.length; i<len; i+=chunkSize)
    result.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
  return result;
}

// chunk an array into couples of 2 
let chunkedArray = [chunk(splitArray, 2)]
console.log (chunkedArray)
// ["-80.486470", "43.390095"], ["-80.486854", "43.390228"],
// ["-80.486796", "43.389998"], ["-80.486292", "43.389968"],
// ["-80.486282", "43.390030"]

// transform chunked array into an object
var objs = chunkedArray.map(function (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (res, curr) {
    var [key, value] = curr;
    res[key] = value;
    return res;
  }, {});
});

console.log(objs);

// Current output

//[{
// -80.486282: "43.390030",
// -80.486292: "43.389968",
// -80.486470: "43.390095",
// -80.486796: "43.389998",
// -80.486854: "43.390228"
// }]

// Desired output 
//  [{ "lng": -80.486282, "lat": 43.390030 },
//   { "lng": -80.486292, "lat": 43.389968 },
//   { "lng": -80.486470, "lat": 43.390095 },
//   { "lng": -80.486796, "lat": 43.389998 },
//   { "lng": -80.486854, "lat": 43.390228 }]
```

What would be the best way to transform chunked array into a `lng`/`lat` object?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like your desired output is sorted. Is this a requirement? If so, do you need to sub-sort on `lat` for tied `lng` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below function.

```js
function getCoordinates(str) {
    const arr = str.split(', ');
    const finalArr = [];

    for (var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i+=2) {
        finalArr.push({
            "lng": parseFloat(arr[i]),
            "lat": parseFloat(arr[i+1])
        });
    }

    return finalArr;
}

let coordinatesString = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, -80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030";
console.log(getCoordinates(coordinatesString));
```

Comment: wow, that looks way more readable thank my concoction, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
let coordinatesString = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, 
-80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030"

let splitArray = coordinatesString.split(', ')
let objs = [];
for(let i = 0; i < splitArray.length-1; i+=2) {
    objs.push({'lng':splitArray[i], 'lat':splitArray[i+1]});
}
console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where an old-school `for` loop is more useful than `map` and `reduce`. (Also more performant, likely.)

```
let coordinatesString = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, -80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030";
const coordinateObjects = [];
const splitCoordinates = coordinatesString.split(", ");
for(let i = 0; i < splitCoordinates.length; i += 2) {
    coordinateObjects.push({lng: parseFloat(splitCoordinates[i]), lat: parseFloat(splitCoordinates[i + 1])});
}
```

`coordinateObjects` then ends up being

```
[
  { lng: -80.48647, lat: 43.390095 },
  { lng: -80.486854, lat: 43.390228 },
  { lng: -80.486796, lat: 43.389998 },
  { lng: -80.486292, lat: 43.389968 },
  { lng: -80.486282, lat: 43.39003 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is well-formatted, you can use the regex `/(.+?),\s*(.+?)(?:,\s*|$)/` to locate all the pairs, then parse each coordinate to number and create objects with `lat`/`lng` properties. Finally, apply a sort on `lng` (if desired).

If you want to sub-sort based on `lat` for pairs with matching `lng`, you might want to add an epsilon for floating point math and add extra branches to `sort`'s callback.

```js
const coordinates = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, -80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030";

const res = [...coordinates.matchAll(/(.+?),\s*(.+?)(?:,\s*|$)/g)]
  .map(e => ({lng: +e[1], lat: +e[2]}))
  .sort((a, b) => b.lng - a.lng)
;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that uses reduce. The reduce callback has the current index and the original array as the third and fourth parameters. The basic for loop is probably more performant than this.

```
const coordinatesString = "-80.486470, 43.390095, -80.486854, 43.390228, -80.486796, 43.389998, -80.486292, 43.389968, -80.486282, 43.390030";

const coordinates = coordinatesString
    .split(', ')
    .reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
        if (idx % 2 === 0) {
            acc.push({
                lng: Number(curr),
                lat: Number(arr[idx + 1])
            })
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(coordinates);
```

Result should be.

```
[
  { lng: -80.48647, lat: 43.390095 }, 
  { lng: -80.486854, lat: 43.390228 },
  { lng: -80.486796, lat: 43.389998 },
  { lng: -80.486292, lat: 43.389968 },
  { lng: -80.486282, lat: 43.39003 }
]
```